# Show a progress bar by 10% steps

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a progression bar in my HTML witch have the class .

I want it progress by 10 (0, 10, 20, 30, 40, ...) till 100%, where I want to redirect to another page.

Here my JS:

```
for (x=0; x<= 100; x+10) {
    window.setInterval(function(){
        if($('.loading-progress').css('width') != '100%') {
                $('.loading-progress').css("width", x+"%");
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

I do not understand why my code do not works.

Any help please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count `x` in a regular way and..

```
 $('.loading-progress').css("width", Math.floor(x / 10) * 10 + "%");
```

ps: Trust me, you **do NOT need** 10 setInterval timers running all the time. I'm talking about the code below. It prepares 10 timers each of the is executed every 2 seconds until the page reloaded or changed.

```
for (x=0; x<= 100; x+10) {
    window.setInterval(function(){
```

may be you need `setTimeout`, but not a `setInterval`

Another way to do it is below

```js
function update_counter(progress) {
 if (progress <= 100) {
     document.getElementById('bar').style.width = progress + "%";
     setTimeout(function() {update_counter(progress + 10); }, 2000);
 } else {
     alert('Redirect');
 }
}

update_counter(0);
```

```css
.loading-progress {
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px;
    width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class='loading-progress' id='bar'></div>
```

Comment: Amazing answer! Thanks for you time and for the snippet.